# Read long text in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, text

I have a very long document - 40000 words - I would like to display in a styled manner, like html.
I need to display it with headers, paragraphs and bold styling.
I am building an Angular app. I tried loading the converted document as a local html, but it takes a **very** long time.
For instance, I tried this:

```
  var html = this.http.get("../data.html").map(ref => {
     console.log(html);
   } );
```

Are there any other ways I can load this text? Maybe break it up into smaller chunks somehow?

Comment: Any sample code? What have you tried so far? This question seems way too broad...

Comment: @CharlieFish edited with something I tried.

Comment: How many seconds is it taking, how long is this document, what's the format, why do you need to load html in this manner, how's it being served, where is it located, what is your app doing with it.... this question is equivalent to "why is my server slow" with no detail at all

Comment: @bryan60 Edited with more info. Actually I waited a few minutes and it still didn't load.

Comment: Not nearly enough information, answering this is impossible.

Comment: @bryan60 What more info should I supply?

Comment: I asked 7 questions, you answered 1. Have you tried this concept with smaller data and confirmed that it works as expected in that situation? Are you even sure that the data size is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've provided with no other context:

You need to subscribe to the Observable otherwise, nothing will ever happen since Observable execution is lazy:

```
var html = this.http.get("../data.html")
  .map(ref => { 
    console.log(html);
    return ref;
  })
  .subscribe(ref => ...);
```

Also, you're using `console.log(html)` in your `map`, but `html` does not exist in the context of `map` so you would need to do something like:

```
var html = this.http.get("../data.html")
  .map(ref => { 
    console.log(ref); // Does this log appear and what does it contain?
    return ref;
  })
  .subscribe(ref => ...);
```

Finally, `var html` is an Observable not HTML so I'd probably rename this to something a bit more descriptive if you're passing it around and subscribing to the response:

```
const data$ = this.http.get("../data.html")
  .map(ref => { 
    console.log(ref);
    return ref;
  });

// ... do other stuff

data$.subscribe(ref => ...);
```

Or if not passed chain it and `subscribe` which indicates the Observeable has completed:

```
this.http.get("../data.html")
  .map(ref => { 
    console.log(ref);
    return ref;
  }).subscribe(ref => ...);
```

If this doesn't help answer the question it's because you haven't provided enough information, and I'd suggest answering:

1. In the second example what does `console.log(ref)` output?
2. Include more code that provides more context like do you use subscribe already and what does the data you're using look like?
3. Make an example in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com) that replicates the issue. Just click Angular and you get a pre-made Angular application you can drop your code into and then people can hack directly on the issue. Takes tops 5 seconds to setup